# Removing middle number of a queue

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I need to create a method in which I remove the middle number of a Linked queue. [1,2,3,4,5] turns into [1,2,4,5] and if the queue is even-numbered you round down and remove from there. So [1,2,3,4] turns into [1,3,4].

I am unsure how to go by removing the middle number and then adding back in the other numbers I removed.

This is what I currently have.

...

```
public class LinkedQueue {
Node head;
Node front;
Node rear;
int count;
int elements;




public void enqueue(int numEnqueue) {
    Node node = rear;
    rear=new Node();
    rear.numEnqueue=numEnqueue;
    rear.next=null;
    if (front==null) 
        front = rear;
        else    
            node.next = rear;
    count++;
    elements=count;
    }

//
public void dequeue() {
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
    int numEnqueue = front.numEnqueue;
    front = front.next;
    count--;
    System.out.print("\nDequeueing: "+numEnqueue);
    }

}

public void show() {
    Node node = front;
    System.out.print("\n\nQueued linked elements: ");
    while(node!=null) {
        System.out.print(node.numEnqueue+" ");
        node=node.next;
        
    }
    
    
}


public void removeMiddle() {    
    int half = 0;
    half=elements/2;
    for (int i=0;i<half;i++) {
        int numEnqueue = front.numEnqueue;
        front = front.next;
    }

}
  
}
```

...
Driver code

...

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedQueue link=new LinkedQueue();
    link.enqueue(1);
    link.enqueue(7);
    link.enqueue(3);
    link.enqueue(4);
    link.enqueue(9);
    link.enqueue(2);
    link.show();
    link.dequeue();
    
    
    link.enqueue(1);
    link.enqueue(7);
    link.enqueue(3);
    link.enqueue(4);
    link.enqueue(9);
    link.enqueue(2);
    link.removeMiddle();
    link.show();

}



}
```

...
Node code

```
public class Node {
int numEnqueue;
Node next;

}
```

Comment: It has to be a linked queue if that makes a difference. I can't switch to another data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'll offer pseudo code/advice:

- given a queue of length `n`, you need to remove element `(n - 1) / 2`  (`int` arithmetic truncates the fractional part of the division for you).
- in a loop that iterates `(n - 1) / 2` times, starting with the root node, advance to the next node each iteratation
- remove the node the loop ends on

The actual solution is slightly more complicated than this, and you may find that it easier to remove the *next* node due to each node not  having a reference to its predecessor. In which case, iterating to the root would count as one iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I think im starting to understand it better now.